# QGIS Crashes when writing to PDF

Tags: qgis, pdf

I have a very large mapper. Formatted to A1 size with a large area and constraints laid across it.

Every time I try to write to PDF it crashes. It is just due to the size of the file. I don't really want reducing the file quality any more so is there any other options.

I am using QGIS Lisboa.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Do you happen to use old labeling with buffers? More details please.

Comment: Agree, more info are needed. There is a known issue surfacing especially with win32 operating systems, but as far as I remember in qgis master there should be a fix for such OSes.

Comment: have you [opened](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues) a bug report for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that it is just the processing speed of the computer and i need a better computer to publish such large scale maps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease the amount of DPI for your export. For example to 300dpi.

Comment: This is a question and not an answer. Also, 300 dpi is really high and good for printing. One could try to set dpi to 150/200 - that would reduce the output file-size.

Comment: @dirk-brunken this is not a question, it is an answer, albeit, not a very high quality one.

Comment: It was a question when i mentioned it first.. but, yes now it is a way to go.. unless 300 dpi is often default and if so - it would not reduce file-size.