# Print Composer Problems with Export as PDF

Tags: qgis, export, pdf, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [QGIS Crashes when writing to PDF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32338/qgis-crashes-when-writing-to-pdf)

My QGIS crashes during the export of maps to pdf. I already uninstalled and installed QGIS twice. The function worked for several times but quit functioning after a while. Does anyone know what this problem causes? I use a new Mac (2012). Could there be a problem with that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Josi

Answer (score 1):

Do you have labels with buffers, and "old" labelling from properties of the layer? Then you should switch to "new" labelling via the abc-icon.

Comment: Hi Francisco, thanks for your fast reply. Unfortunately I cannot find the questions wit the same content and the solution provided there. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Hi Andre, no, I use the new labeling and I do not have any buffers in use.

Comment: The question with same content is listed on the right under "Linked". Unfortunately, nobody had an answer to that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this bug is related to your problem: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3687

Comment: I finally found out that it WAS the labeling, as mentioned by Andre Joost. Only using the labeling edited with the ABC-icon there were fewer problems. Thanks for the very helpful tipps!