# QGIS 1.8 crashes when exporting from print composer to image on Windows 7

Tags: qgis, export, image, windows-7

My question is similar to [QGIS Crashes when writing to PDF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32338/qgis-crashes-when-writing-to-pdf).
Today, when I try to export to image, QGIS crashes. I've tried opening a new composer to no avail.

This is the problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: qgis.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4fdce845
  Fault Module Name:    QtGui4.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.7.1.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4d5308cc
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00053de0
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Is there something wrong with my QtGui4.dll? Do I not have [enough memory allocated](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/qgis-crash-when-exporting-to-pdf-svg-or-image-td4547367.html)?

Comment: Do you have a 32 bit Win7?

Comment: QGIS Win7 built is 32-bit only, so that should make no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it was simply the size of the image/map i was trying to print/create.

On a side note: I have moved from using the export to PDF button in favour of using file>print> and selecting print to pdf. In this I can adjust the quality of the drawing to high (600dpi) and still create a smaller file size and the risk of crashing has been significantly reduced. I cannot offer an explanation to this just that it works.

Also the quality of the drawing has been significantly improved and colours are printing as they should be. With the export button colours were appearing different to that of which I had plotted.

Give it a try and see the difference in file size and quality. then possibly print the resulting pdf.

[image]

Comment: Yep, it was definitely a file size problem. I shrunk the file size and am easily able to print. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I guess same as with writing to PDF, if the image is very large:

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/qgis-and-Large-Format-Print-td5016300.html

Try the QGIS Master available by OSGEO4W installer (qgis-dev package). Maybe the problem is fixed there already.